# Dynamicly generated html table with JQ datetimepicker to array

Tags: php, jquery, html

Please help..
Here's a dynamic 10-row html table with datetimepicker input area. I need to get all the datetime values but only the last cell data is available. What is wrong with the code?

```
<form action="atab.php" method="post">
<table>
...    
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){        
    echo"<tr>";
    ...
    <td><input class="datetimepicker" type="text" name="datet" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".datetimepicker" ).datetimepicker();
    });
    </script>
    </td>       
    <?php
    echo"</tr>";
}
}
echo'</table><input id="subm" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit" name="subm"    value="Send" /></form><hr />';
...
```

and some php:

```
<?php
    $date=array($_POST['datet']);
    foreach ($date as $value){
        echo $value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to declare the input name as an array type

```
<input class="datetimepicker" type="text" name="datet[]" />
```

then

```
$date=$_POST['datet'];
```

Also there is no need to initialize the plugin within the loop, move the below lines out of the loop

```
$(function() {
    $( ".datetimepicker" ).datetimepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<input class="datetimepicker" type="text" name="datet" />
```

to

```
<input class="datetimepicker" type="text" name="datet[]" />
```

and try this:

```
<?php

    foreach ($_POST['datet'] as $value){
        echo $value."<br>";
    }
```